# Is ld called at both compile time and runtime?

Tags: compilation, linker

I am trying to understand how linking and loading work.  My understanding is that the Unix program "ld" contains both linking and loading functionality.  When gcc is invoked, after preprocessing, compiling, and assembling, the linker is called which links all object files and .a files into an executable, along with minimal instructions for how shared libraries should be "connected" (what is the correct terminology here?) at runtime.  This linker is ld.

At runtime, my understanding is that the executable is loaded into memory, although I'm not sure how.  My specific questions are as follows:

1) Are shared object files being "linked" at compile time, or is there another word for what is happening?
2) At runtime, is ld being called for a second time?  How can I see proof of this for my executable (on Linux and on MacOS)?
3) Are shared object files being "linked" at runtime, or is there another word for the process when shared objects are read from the location in LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Is ld called at both compile time and runtime?

No: ld is *not* called at *either* compile or runtime.

> When gcc is invoked, after preprocessing, compiling, and assembling, the linker is called which links all object files and .a files into an executable

Most moderately complicated programs use *separate* compilation and linking steps.

At compilation, a set of relocatable object files is produced (preprocessing, compilation and assembling are invoked at that step). Optionally the `.o` files are archived into an archive library (`libsomething.a`).

*Then* a link step is performed (often this is called "static linking", to differentiate this step from "dynamic loading" that will happen at runtime), producing an executable, or a shared library. Only at *this* step is `/usr/bin/ld` is invoked. On Linux, `ld` is part of the binutils package.

> along with minimal instructions for how shared libraries should be "connected"

The linker records which shared libraries are required at runtime, and possibly which versions of libraries or symbols are required.

It also records which *runtime loader* should be used to load the required shared libraries.

> At runtime, my understanding is that the executable is loaded into memory, although I'm not sure how.

The kernel loads executable into memory, and checks whether runtime loader was requested at static link time. If it was, the dynamic loader is *also* loaded into memory, and execution control is passed to it (instead of the main executable).

It is then the job of the dynamic loader to examine the executable for instructions on which other libraries are required, check whether correct versions can be found, loading them into memory, and arranging things such that symbol resolution will work between the main executable and the shared libraries. *This* is the runtime loading step, often also called dynamic linking.

The dynamic loader can be part of the OS, but on Linux it's part of libc (GLIBC, uClibc and musl each have their own loader).

Answer (score 0):

No. ld is linking as in creating a library or exe, ld*.so is the loading part.  Also ld*.so is part of the OS, not the gcc suite afaik.  ld is generally part of (GNU) binutils on a gcc based system (but e.g. usually LLVM lld in a LLVM based system)

ld*.so is ld-linux-{arch}.so.2 on Linux and /libexec/ld-elf.so on e.g. FreeBSD.

Comment: ld-linux is *not* part of the OS on Linix. You can have several different ones installed on the same system at the same time.

Comment: It's part of glibc it seems.  That knowledge doesn't make sense logically however. My point however was more that it was not part of the parts that are portable to other OS like binutils and gcc.